# Evaluate $\int_\gamma \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1} \ dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, contour-integration

> Define the semicircular arc $\gamma_R$ by $\gamma_R(t)=Re^{it}$, where $0\leq t\leq\pi$ and $R>1$ is a real constant. Let $\gamma$ be the join of $\gamma_R$ and the line segment from $-R$ to $R$. Also, $z\in\text{Range}(\gamma_R)$.
>
> Evaluate, $$\int_\gamma \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1} \ dz. \ \ \ \ (1)$$

I have already shown the following results:
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\right|&\leq\frac{1}{R^2-1}, \\
\left|\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\right|&\leq\frac{R\pi}{R^2-1} \ \ \text{(by the ML Lemma)}.
\end{align}

I have tried to solve $(1)$, by parametrising the line segment $\gamma$ and using the contour integral formula, $$\int_{0}^{1} f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t) \ dt.$$
But the working became to convoluted. Is there an easier way?

Comment: "Is there an easier way" - Yes and No in general. Often some substitutions will be made, but unless you can get away with using residue calculus, Cauchy Integral formula, etc., the definition is going to be the way to go

Comment: I would really like to use the CIF, but I thought this relied on a closed and simple contour. Here, $\gamma$ is just a line segment. Can we use the CIF in this case?

Comment: Oh wait, $\gamma$ need not be closed, only simply connected. So we can use the CIF?

Comment: Another common trick is to first parameterize it as an integral of the form $\int_0^\pi f(t) dt$ and then to substitute $u = 2t$ so we get an integral of the form $\int_0^{2\pi} f(u/2) dt$ which we may then use the theory of closed contours on when you transform it back into a contour integral.

Comment: Another trick would be to use the Taylor Expansion of the exponential function and integrate termwise.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. I was wondering, is it possible to consider $$\int_\gamma+\int_{\gamma_R}=\int_{\gamma_r+\gamma}$$ and the just rearrange for $\int_\gamma$

Comment: Absolutely, and that is a common trick for applying the CIF or residue calculus. However, as I just mentioned in my answer, your $\gamma$ is the *join* of a line segment with a circular arc, and so is a closed semi-circle. Thus this question is much easier than when I thought it was just a semi-circle because I misread!

Comment: Solving for $\int_{\gamma_R}$ is proving difficult. I get the numerator as $$e^{iRe^{it}}$$

Answer (score 0):

I misread your question initially. This is in fact quite easy to do via the Residue Calculus: note that $\gamma$ is not just a line segment, but a semi-circular contour. Notice that the integrand has poles at $\pm i$. Only the pole at $i$ could matter, and so we have three cases:

$R<1:$ we don't include any poles so the integrand is zero by Cauchy's Theorem.

$R>1:$ we include the pole at $i$ so our integral is $2\pi i \operatorname{Res(i)} = (2\pi i)\left(\frac{-i}{2e}\right) = \pi/e$

$R = 1:$ Things become a bit complicated because the pole at $i$ is on the boundary of the circle, but we can use the Cauchy Principle Value to associate a value with the integral

---

Since in your case $R>1$ we can safely say the answer is $\pi/e.$